# Send email in trigger to created user

Tags: apex, trigger

I need an apex class and trigger code for account can be converted into user and same way send an email to new user.

when we get into web to lead form, it can be converted into account and contact..after that contact can be need to convert into user and automatically it sends mail to represented new user.

i had a code for account converted into user and sending email to user individually, but when i combined and using both the codes i am getting an error and could not be updated an output.

## Trigger

```
trigger SendEmailToAccount on Contact (after insert) 
{

    if(Trigger.isAfter)
        {

    if(Trigger.isInsert )

    { 
                //helper class for single email but bulk messages

    HelperContactTrigger.sendEmail(trigger.new);

    }

    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate )

    {           

    //HelperContactTrigger.sendEmailafter(trigger.new);

    }

}
```

## Apex Class

```
public without sharing class HelperContactTrigger 
{

    public static List<Contact> sendEmail(List<Contact> Contacts)

    {
    List<User> lstUser = new List<User>();
    Profile objProfile = [select Id from Profile where name = 'Customer Community Plus User'];
    for(Contact objCon : Contacts)
    {
        if(objCon.AccountId!=NULL && objCon.Email!=NULL)
        {
            lstUser.add(new User(contactId=objCon.Id, username=objCon.Email+'.denfiif211n', firstname=objCon.FirstName,
                        lastname=objCon.LastName, email=objCon.Email,communityNickname = objCon.LastName + '_MNGNNSLWI',
                        alias = string.valueof(objCon.FirstName.substring(0,1) + objCon.LastName.substring(0,1)), profileid = objProfile.Id, emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                    languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles'));

        }
    }    
    HelperContactTrigger.createPortalUsers(JSON.serialize(lstUser));
    return NULL;
    }

    @future
    public static void createPortalUsers(String strUser)
    {
    List<User> lstUser =  (List<User>)JSON.deserialize(strUser,List<User>.class);
    insert lstUser;

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(User objUser : lstUser)
    {

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
            List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
            sendTo.add('pankaj.ganwani50@gmail.com');
            mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
            mail.setSubject('New User');   
            //mail.settemplateId('00X280000018elQ');
            //mail.saveAsActivity=false;
            //mail.setTargetObjectId(objUser.Id);    
            mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi'); 
            mails.add(mail);
    }
    system.debug('------'+Messaging.sendEmail(mails));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error which you got.

Comment: Please post error messages and relevant code sections in your question. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Check [DMLOptions Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm#emailheader%20//%20To%20send%20Email%20notification)

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOption = new Database.DMLOptions();
// This will send Notification Email to User
dmlOption.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
Database.insert(userObj, dmlOption); // Assuming userObj is User Object instance
```

Comment: my code is above mentioned can u please make use of that

Comment: @RavikumarSurapati Post the error message too.

Comment: it did not send an email..just converting an user